# UIButton action is not triggered after constraint layouts changed

Tags: swift, uibutton, touch, action

I have got an UIButton on a storyboard ViewController. When I load data into the form and the layout is significantly changing the button does not recognise the touch action.

I have figured out that when button is visible on the scrollview right after it if filled with data, the touch action works.

If the data too long and the button is not visible at first, just when it is scrolled into the display, the touch action does not work.

I was checking if something is above the button, but nothing. I have tried to change the zPosition of the button, not solved the problem.

What can be the issue?

I have made custom classes from the UIScrollView and the UIButton to check how the touches event triggered. It is showing the same behaviour, which is obvious. If the button is visible right at the beginning, the UIButton's touchesBegan event is triggered. If the button moves down and not visible at the beginning, it is never triggered, but the scrollview's touchesBegan is called instead.

Depending on the size of the data I load into the page sometimes the button is visible at the beginning, but the form can be still scrolled a bit. In this case the button still work, so it seems that this behaviour is not depending on if the scrollview is scrolled before or not, just on the initial visibility of the button.

Is there any layout or display refresh function which should be called to set back the behaviour to the button?

[image: My storyboard setup:]

The code portion which ensures that the contentview is resized for the scroll if the filled data requires bigger space.

```
func fillFormWithData() {
    dispDescription.text = jSonData[0]["advdescription"]
    dispLongDescription.text = jSonData[0]["advlongdesc"]
    priceandcurrency.text = jSonData[0]["advprice"]! + " " + jSonData[0]["advpricecur"]!
    validitydate.text = jSonData[0]["advdate"]!
    contentview.layoutIfNeeded()
    let contentRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollview.frame.width, height: uzenetbutton.frame.origin.y+uzenetbutton.frame.height+50)

    contentview.frame.size.height = contentRect.size.height
    scrollview.contentSize = contentview.bounds.size
}
```

[image: After data load contentview+scrollview jumps to the bottom]

[image: After scroll the content view is cut to the original screensize]

Ok, so another update. I have coloured the contentview background to blue and the scrollview background to white. When I load the data and resize the layout constraints, the contentview is resizing as expected, however now the scrollview is going to the bottom. After I scroll the view it is resizing to the original size which fits the screen. Now the button is only recognised when I touch the are which is blue behind. With the white background it is not recognised anymore, so it seems that the scrollview is hiding the button.

Comment: show us the code that puts the views together and the view hierachy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found the solution in another chain, once it became clear that the scrollview's contentview is resizing on scroll event to the original size. (Not clear why this is like this, but that is the fact.)

So I had to add a height constraint to the contentview in the storyboard and create an outlet to it and adjust this constraint when the content size is changing, like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var ContentViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

func fillFormWithData() {
    dispDescription.text = jSonData[0]["advdescription"]
    dispLongDescription.text = jSonData[0]["advlongdesc"]
    priceandcurrency.text = jSonData[0]["advprice"]! + " " + jSonData[0]["advpricecur"]!
    validitydate.text = jSonData[0]["advdate"]!
    contentview.layoutIfNeeded()
    let contentRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollview.frame.width, height: uzenetbutton.frame.origin.y+uzenetbutton.frame.height+50)

    contentview.bounds = contentRect
    scrollview.contentSize = contentRect.size

    ----------- This is the key line to the success ----------
    ContentViewHeight.constant = contentRect.size.height
    ----------------------------------------------------------
}
```

After this is added, it works perfectly.

[image: Contentsize is perfectly as should be]

Comment: I think I found the issue with your project. You need to move the MessageButton(UzenetButton) above DispDescription label in the object inspector in that way it will always be above your message textView

Answer (score 2):

Let me get this clear the button is added in storyboard and it is a spritekit project?? If you are using zPosition?? Why don’t u connect the UIButton via the assistant editor as an IBAction then the action is always tied to the button.

You can also do it differently

Create an SKLabelNode and put it on the screen where you want to have the button and then set a name to it as myButton

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event:
UIEvent?) {
 if let touch = touches.first {
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    let tappedNodes = nodes(at: location)
      for node in tappedNodes {
        if node.name == "myButton" {
           // call your action here
        }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT 1: 
You could also try auto resizing your scrollView.content this works also if you are adding any views via the app or programmatically

```
    private func resizeScrollView(){
    print("RESIZING THE SCROLLVIEW from \(scrollView.contentSize)")
    for view in scrollView.subviews {
        contentRect = contentRect.union(view.frame)
    }
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentRect.size.width, height: contentRect.size.height + 150)
    print("THE CONTENT SIZE AFTER RESIZING IS: \(scrollView.contentSize)")
}
```

EDIT 2: I think I found the issue with your project. You need to move the MessageButton(UzenetButton) above DispDescription label in the object inspector in that way it will always be above your message textView.
At the moment the UzeneButton is at the very far back in your view hierarchy so if your textView is resizing whilst editing it covers the button that is why you cannot click on it.

Comment: This is a simple UI project, not spritekit project, however I was guessing that the problem might be the same as on a spritekit project. IBAction is created, but it is also not triggered. I guess that there is something happens when I use the layoutIfNeeded() function to recalculate the content view size for the scrollview. If the content view size is smaller or equal than the original size then button gets the call. If bigger then the initial contentsize than the scrollview's touchesBegan is called and the IBAction is not triggered.

Comment: I just would like to understand the logic behind to solve the issue natively, but I cannot find out what is causing the problem. Via a similar solution I could pass the control over to the button, for sure, as I have tried it already, but I want to have a bulletproof solution. Button should work as designed. So needs a definite solution for this without a workaround.

Comment: Are you putting the button into the scrollview as the scrollview might be above the button and that could be the problem

Comment: Yes, I put it on the scrollview in the storyboard editor. I was guessing the same, but how can I put back UIButton above the scrollview. I was trying to use the bringSubview(toFront: ) function with the UIButton, but it did not change anything.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of my storyboard and the data filling code which resizes the content view.

Comment: This is really weird thing. I have managed to have such a content size that the button is partially visible on the screen. If I touch it, it works properly. But after I scroll it to fully in view. All touches goes to the scrollview's touchesBegan function.

Comment: Orulok hogy sikerult

Comment: Have you tried my EDIT 2: ?? that should solve the issue natively.

Comment: No, the issue was solved with the auto layout constraint setting as native solution as I described in my solution. Your solution is similar to what I was trying before, by changing the content view size, but the scrolling was always setting it back to the original value. So content view size setting is not working. Changing the order in the hierarchy is also a dead end street. I have tried it too. Taking out the control from the scroll view is definitely works, but it is not what I wanted. So I have implemented the constraint update solution and it works.

Answer (score 2):

See @Endre Olah,

1. To make situation more clear do one more thing, set  **clipToBound** property of **contentview** to **true**.
2. you will notice that after loading of data your button not fully visible, it means it is shifting **out of bound** of its **parentView (ContentView)**
3. And that's why button is not taking your touch. However, if you carefully touch upper part of button it still do its job. Because upper part is still in **bound** of **ContentView**
4. **Solution** : 
   After loading of data you have to make sure that you increase height of **ContentView** such that **button** should never go **out of bound** of its **parentView(ContentView)**.

**FOR EXAMPLE**

```
@IBOutlet var heightConstraintOfContentView : NSLayoutConstraint!
```

> After loading of data

```
let contentRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollview.frame.width, height: uzenetbutton.frame.origin.y+uzenetbutton.frame.height+50)
heightConstraintOfContentView.constant = contentRect.size.height
contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: This was my case, what I explained above. As scrolling was setting back the content view size to the initial size, the content size adjustment was not enough.

Comment: so, i think you should not directly change height of contentView. But instead you should make a IBOutlet of height Constraint of ContentView and then after loading of data change its constant property accordingly. I am Editing my answer with some sample code.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution as I have written it in my answer. Just read the marked answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use following steps when I need to use scrollview with dynamic content:

1) Firstly add a scrollView with *top, bottom, trailing* and *leading* is **0** to super view.

[image: Scroll View Constraints]

2) Add a *view* to *scrollView* and *view*'s trailing, leading bottom and top space to *scrollView* can be set to 0 (or you can add margin optionally).

[image: view Constraints]

3) Now, you should add UI elements like buttons, labels with appropriate top, bottom, trailing and leading margins to each other.

4) Lastly, add equal height and equal width constraint to *view* with *Safe Area*:

[image]

and change equal height priority of *view* to **250**:

[image]

It should solve your problem with *UIScrollView*.

Comment: This is to solve the problem to get it always the same size as the safe are size, but my problem was different. I had to resize the content view dynamically. But once I have scrolled the view it returned to the original size even if the content size was much bigger. It would not be a problem if I would not need interaction to the content. In this case a button.