# How to keep fonts the same size across (where possible) different controls with autolayout?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, autolayout, interface-builder, uifont

I have several UILabels which span a different number of lines. I've set the font / size for each with different sizing classes. I've also set a minimum size.

However I can't keep fonts the same size.

How do I achieve this with autolayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend suggested a UIStackView, which is awesome

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how many UILabels you have. That's why you can start with adding a `UIScrollView` to your view controller that enables dynamic content. (or you can make it by using `UITableView`)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52079807/2807814) you can follow the steps to create `UIScrollView` with dynamic content.

After that, you should add your `UILabel`s with bottom, top, trailing and leading constraints. It will resize label height regarding to your text length. Also font and size remain same.